# Measure SUM doesn't sum values in certain column

Tags: sql-server, ssas, olap

We have been successfully running several cubes on our server.

Recently I began to develop another cube and got stuck with weird problem.

My setup is:

- SQL Server fact table, one field is Integer,
- that table is added to Data Source View,
- there is newly created cube with dimensions and measures,
- one of measure is SUM of the forementioned field (simple, classic basic measure in Cube Structure->Measures)

The thing is... it always displays zero. Other SUMs on similar fields work perfectly.

What I've tried:

- the dimensions are crossed with Measure Groups in Dimensions Tab,
- the field exists, contains integer values,
- the SUM measure is created correctly,
- I've tried changing proprtied of measure, DataType to BigInt and Source->DataType to BigInt, as I suspected there could be some datatype overflow,
- I've tried creating calculated field in Data Source View which is a copy of forementioned field and creating a SUM of it - no success,
- I've created the SUM Measure once again,
- I've deployed cube to different database,
- I've checked the name of the field (we had issues with case-sensitivity of SSAS in previous cubes)

Of course I've been processing the cube and so on.

Don't get me wrong, I've developed three cubes already, with multiple dimensions, measures, MDX calculations and so on. And I've run out of ideas. What am I missing? The SUM doesn't work for one field and one field only, the other SUMs on same datatype field in the same cube in the same fact table work perfectly - what could've gone wrong?

Comment: Is this vield nullable in your table? Try adding `ISNULL(MyValue, 0) AS MyValue to your datasource view

Answer (score 2):

I expect your dataset contains null values. If your dataset contains NULL values the result of SUM(OneField) will always be NULL.

SUM(COALESCE(OneField,0) or SUM(ISNULL(OneField,0)) should allow you to summarize the column.

example
select sum(1 + null ) results in NULL

select sum(1 + coalesce(null,0)) results in 1

Comment: I've double checked it, the field contains no NULL values, but I'm gonna try to COALESCE it anyway, maybe SSAS knows better.

Comment: Unfortunately nothing has changed, I modified the copy of the field in Data Source View, added COALESCE and SUM is based on that modified field, but it still displays zero.

Comment: Jesus Christ I'm so dumb. I just realised that I'm looking at the SUM in the aggregation that never has values in that field. NEVERMIND, I should vanish right now.

Answer (score 0):

I've realised that I was checking the results of the field in the hierarchy field that never has these values in it. I'm blind.